# use .h defines in javascript

Tags: javascript, header-files

I want to use defines in .h files in my JavaScript.

I have input from user HTML file,
and want to show them in the HTML file like:

```
input = 5
```

the .h file contains define:

```
#define CODE 5
```

I want to show to the user the output: CODE

Comment: You can't mix JavaScript with C!

Answer (score 6):

**JavaScript does not have .h files. It is not C/C++.**

You could achieve this by using an [object map / associative object](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html):

```
map = {
    1: "FISH",
    2: "CHIPS",
    3: "EAT",
    4: "SLEEP",
    5: "CODE",
}
input = 5
alert(map[5]) // Will alert CODE, as required.
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can use C preprocessor (gpp for example) for js-file. But C preprocessor doesn't work as you have described. It will replace «CODE» with «5».

So if you want replace exactly number, you must use it as index of object or array. Otherwise you also can use variable or even preprocessor.

You can't replace simple number with string.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support *.h files

You can load header file with defined constanst:

header.js:

```
var CODE = 5;
```

and evalute it in main code

main.js:

```
var code = $.get("header.js")
eval(code.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no .h files for making your own programing language or functions but you can make functions that make your own functions or commands

here's a way to do it:
https://www.guru99.com/learn-functions-in-javascript-in-5-minutes.html